# Why do I need to append % right after { of multido rather than right after } of pstVerb?

Tags: pstricks

Why do I need to insert `%` right after the opening curly brace `{` of `multido`  rather than right after the closing `}` of `\pstVerb`? In my mental model, the unnecessary white spaces exist after the `\pstVerb` call so they must be removed by appending `%` right after `}` of `\pstVerb`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m](8,8)
    \multido{\ix=1+1,\ic=97+1}{8}
    {% <-- this comment is necessary but I don't understand why.
        \pstVerb{/hx \ix\space .5 sub def}
        \uput[d](!hx 0){$\char\ic\mathstrut$}
        \uput[l](!0 hx){$\ix\mathstrut$}
        \multido{\iy=1+1,\io=\ix+1}{8}
        {       
            \psframe[origin={\ix,\iy},fillstyle=\ifodd\io solid\else vlines\fi,hatchsep=.5pt,hatchcolor=lightgray](-1,-1)
            \rput(!hx \iy\space .5 sub){$(\iy,\ix)$}
        }
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

every macro which is declared as a PSTricks object like

```
\def\xyz{\pst@object{xyz}}
\def\xyz@i{%
   ...%
}
```

will kill all preceding glue. `\pstVerb` is not a PSTricks object or in short: it is a normal TeX macro and `\psframe` is such an object.

A shorter version:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m](8,8)
  \multido{\ix=1+1,\rx=0.5+1.0,\ic=97+1}{8}{%
    \uput[d](\rx,0){$\char\ic\mathstrut$}
    \uput[l](0,\rx){$\ix\mathstrut$}
    \multido{\iy=1+1,\ry=0.5+1.0,\io=\ix+1}{8}{%
      \psTextFrame[fillstyle=\ifodd\io solid\else none\fi,fillcolor=lightgray]%
         (\ix,\iy)(!\ix\space 1 sub \iy\space 1 sub){$(\iy,\ix)$}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why  does the `%` come before `\pstVerb{...}` rather than after `\pstVerb{...}`?

Comment: `\uput` has a `\pst@killglue`

Comment: Does it make sense to insert `\pst@killglue` in `\pstVerb` to kill the unnecessary whitespaces automatically?

Comment: no, makes no real sense.